# How to fix the look of KDE apps in LXDE?

Tags: kde, themes, appearance, lxde

I am using LXDE in Ubuntu 11.10. KDE apps like Kate and Kile have an ugly Windows-95ish look when run in LXDE, but look fine in Gnome. How do I choose the theme/widget style for KDE apps in LXDE?

In case it matters, I installed LXDE by using the package `lxde`, and not `lubuntu-desktop` since the latter would bring in various things like abiword which I didn't want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install QT4 COnfiguration.

`sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconfig`

[image]

Then Select GTk+ in GUI Style

Comment: This does not work for me, starting a Qt app gives `QGtkStyle was unable to detect the current GTK+ theme.` This is because LXDE uses a settings daemon instead of a gtkrc-2.0 file

Answer (score 1):

I'm not directly familiar with Kate and Kile - I'm assuming that they are QT based applications.

For QT-based apps you should use `qt4-qtconfig` and select the GTK style to make QT apps look similar to GTK based apps that Lubuntu/LXDE mainly use.

To install this package (if it isn't already installed):

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconfig
```